# How to upload dat file using JSP, Java (Struts.)?

Tags: java, file-upload, struts

I need to upload .dat file from jsp page. I am using struts. I am using

```
<input type="file" name="file"  size=25 />
```

in jsp and in action class

```
FileUploadForm uploadForm = (FileUploadForm) form;
FormFile file = uploadForm.getFile();
InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
```

After this I am confused. I dont want to open and read the dat file as the size of the may be big. I just wanna create/copy the same dat file in some specified path in server as per the original name of the dat file. How to do it?

And if there is no other way but read it then also tell me how read and write it to dat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the tasks you need to complete in order to finish this task:

1. Decide where uploaded files are to be stored on the server
2. Open an output stream to a file in the appropriate location
3. Copy from the uploaded data from it's input stream to the output
   stream

Here is some pseudo-code, utilizing Apache IOUtils to copy the stream data:

```
final FormFile formFile = uploadForm.getFile();
final String outPath = "/somerootpath/" + formFile.getFileName();
final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
IOUtils.copy(formFile.getInputStream(), outStream);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But compiler error is coming and saying "The method IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream) is undefined for the type IOUtils" and same for IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);

Comment: To use Apache IOUtils you need to [download it](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) and include the JAR in your build path.